# dplyr, filter if both values are above a number

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set like such.

`df = data.frame(Business = c('HR','HR','Finance','Finance','Legal','Legal','Research'), Country = c('Iceland','Iceland','Norway','Norway','US','US','France'), Gender=c('Female','Male','Female','Male','Female','Male','Male'), Value =c(10,5,20,40,10,20,50))`

I need to be filter out all rows where both male value and female value are >= 10. For example, Iceland HR should be removed as well as Research France.

I've tried `df %>% group_by(Business,Country) %>% filter((Value>=10))` but this filters out any value less than 10. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- reshape(df,idvar = c('Business','Country'),timevar = 'Gender',direction = 'wide')
df2 %>% mutate(Index=ifelse(Value.Female>=10 & Value.Male>=10,1,0)) %>%
  filter(Index==1) -> df3
df4 <- reshape2::melt(df3[,-5],idvar=c('Business','Country'))

  Business Country     variable value
1  Finance  Norway Value.Female    20
2    Legal      US Value.Female    10
3  Finance  Norway   Value.Male    40
4    Legal      US   Value.Male    20
```

Comment: not quite, i'd want to remove HR Iceland and keep only Norway and US here.

Comment: Just place `Index==1` @TedMosby I updated the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use two `ave` steps, one with `length`, one with `min`.

```
df <- df[with(df, ave(Value, Country, FUN=length)) == 2, ]
df[with(df, ave(Value, Country, FUN=min)) >= 10, ]
#   Business Country Gender Value
# 3  Finance  Norway Female    20
# 4  Finance  Norway   Male    40
# 5    Legal      US Female    10
# 6    Legal      US   Male    20
```

Notice that this also works if we disturb the data frame.

```
set.seed(42)
df2 <- df[sample(1:nrow(df)), ]

df2 <- df2[with(df2, ave(Value, Country, FUN=length)) == 2, ]
df2[with(df2, ave(Value, Country, FUN=min)) >= 10, ]
#   Business Country Gender Value
# 5    Legal      US Female    10
# 6    Legal      US   Male    20
# 3  Finance  Norway Female    20
# 4  Finance  Norway   Male    40
```

Comment: This is nice solution, but I need to make sure each Business and Country have both a male and female variable and that both those values are above 10.

Comment: @TedMosby `ave` is also capable of this. Just updated my answer!